# WPF - WrapPanel Child Item Height

Tags: c#, wpf, wrappanel

**There is a WrapPanel. When I add a new post, it looks like the photo below. If the height of the new item is larger than the old item in the row, height is increases. How I can I do without increasing? Thanks for your helps.**

[image: Now]

**It gonna look like this:**

[image: I want]

Comment: You have no code, its impossible to answer this without starting from scratch.

Comment: Its just a classic WrapPanel there is no extra anything.

Comment: You could give items a fixed height, using style, or inside your datatemplate.